# Wordpress shows /%EF%BB%BF/ in URL for template page

Tags: wordpress, utf-8

I stumbled across this problem today. Only one page of a wordpress template has this really strange URL

```
http://www.mysite.nl/folder-x/%ef%bb%bfsander-john-en-marie-cecile/
```

None of the other files that use this same template file have this strange URL

```
http://www.mysite.nl/folder-x/ilonka-meisje-zonder-hoofd/
```

I read somewhere that this has something to do with a UTF-8 BOM but wouldn't that then be across the whole template? There is no extra script being used on this page. It's just a normal txt wordpress page.

I disabled the plugins that could interfere what I have red, but this didn't help. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing the post, and setting the slug again? (Editing the permalink.)

Comment: I am facing similar issue (`%EF%BF%BC` characters, but at the end of the links). Unfortunately editing the post is not helping.

Comment: @firasd may I know the reason of doing so?

Comment: This worked for me - simple!!  I needed to clear cache afterwards to see the new URI